# How do I display Modal Dialog in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a MVC, ASP.Net application and I want to create a dialog form.I created a view(*.ascx).I am openning this from controller with  return View("Questionnaire", list);

The code for my control is  this :

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Questionnaire>>" %>

 <div id="dialog">

 <table>
  <tr><td >Question</td><td colspan="2">Yes/No</td></tr>
    <%  foreach (Questionnaire s in Model)
        {
     %>
      <tr>
 <td><%=s.Question%></td>
 <td><input name="Input<%=s.Id %>"  style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
 <td><input name="Input<%=s.Id %>"  style="text-align:center;" type="radio" /></td>
 </tr>
  <%
    }
  %>  
 </table>

  </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
     }); 

     $(function () {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
      });
    </script>
```

But my view doesn't look like a dialog box .Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You have `<script>` inside `<div>` ?!

Comment: I moved script outside of div.I am new to Javascript/ Ajax and i don't know exactly how to put .

Comment: there is a example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541821/how-to-simplify-my-statefull-interlaced-modal-dialogs-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: I copy on my page:                                                <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
 <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div> and i copy also section script : <script>
 $(function() {
  // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
  $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
 
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
   height: 140,
   modal: true
  });
 });
 </script> but nothing happen .It doesn't look like a modal dialog

Comment: if my link with examples is ok for you, please check you CSS files.